# USB 3.0 flash drive doesn't work on USB 3.0 hub?

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-3

I purchased a [Transcend 128GB USB 3.0 flash drive](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00JKATVM4) last month. It does *not* work on the two USB 3.0 ports on my computer, which has an [ASUS Rampage III Extreme motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131642&cm_re=asus_rampage_iii_extreme-_-13-131-642-_-Product). The device doesn't even light up at all. Yet other flash drives (non-3.0) work fine on those ports. An Anker USB 3.0 hub that I just purchased works fine, too.

Plugging that Transcend flash drive into another USB port (2.0, presumably), it lights up and is recognized immediately.

What gives?

Comment: did you try any other USB3 device with your USB port?

Comment: Also, are you saying that plugging the USB 3.0 hub into the same USB 3.0 ports works?  Have you tested the Transcend drive on a different USB 3.0 port (like on another computer)?  Were you able to verify that the hub operates at USB 3.0 speed?

Comment: @Sachith: Yes, I plugged in a USB 3.0 hub and it is recognized and works fine.

Comment: @fixer1234: Yes, the hub works fine on the exact same USB 3.0 ports on the mobo. Sadly, I do not have any other USB 3.0 ports at my disposal. Well, I might have access to one at work Monday; I'll give it a try then if I can remember to. And I do not know how to test the speed of the hub; any help is appreciated.

Comment: It could be a counterfeit product. Test it on another computer that has USB3.0, and if it works, check its data transfer speed (e.g. http://www.pcworld.com/article/2455205/test-the-speed-of-your-usb-drives.html). If it's broken or very slow, retrun it to the vendor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more research and looked in my Device Manager. I did see one "USB Hub" or some such with an exclamation point on it. And some of my research suggested updating drivers. So I went to ASUS' site and downloaded USB 3.0 drivers, figuring it couldn't hurt, even if they were already installed.

It turns out they were *not* already installed. So my problem really just boils down to the fact that I didn't have USB 3.0 drivers. I just assumed that Windows 7 automatically downloaded and installed them when I changed out motherboards years ago. I guess that's what I get for trusting Windows 7.

So, let this be a notice for anyone else who might be having similar issues: Don't trust Windows 7's automatic driver installation. Download and install the drivers yourself for the USB 3.0 ports on your computer.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time for such a trivial issue.

Comment: Windows 7 does not ship with USB 3.0 drivers. // Don’t forget to accept your answer.